# EWS exchangelib python: Unable to extract the content of an email using '.body' attribute

Tags: python, email, exchangewebservices, python-3.5, exchangelib

This is the email output when I ran '.body' on my email object. I got the following output:

**Sender: xxxxxxxxx.com**

**Subject: yyyyyyyy**

**Message-Id: xxxx-xxxx-xx-xxx-xxx@mail.outlook.com>**

**To: xxxxxxx.com**

instead of the email body text. Am i missing something here ? or is there an alternative way to extract email body content using any of the available ews attributes ( message-id etc)

Below is my python code :

```
account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address=username_to_access,
    config=config,
    autodiscover=False,
    access_type=DELEGATE
)

items = account.inbox.all()

for mail in items:    
        print(str(mail.body))



OUTPUT:
Sender: xxxxxxxxxxx.com
Subject: xxxxxxxxxx
Message-Id: 
<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@mail.outlook.com>
To: xxxxxxxxxx.com
```

Comment: Maybe that is just the actual body of your email? Can you check that with another Exchange client? There's no magic going on with the `body` attribute - exchangelib just passes along what it receives from EWS.

Comment: Thanks @ErikCederstrand for your prompt response. Can it be something associated with the mailbox account permissions like Impersonation or Delegate ? Meanwhile, i'll just check with my admin to confirm the actual content i'm getting to be correct or not

Comment: No, it shouldn't have anything to do with the access type. You can enable DEBUG logging to see the exact contents of the `<Body>` tag in the response XML, which should hopefully tell you that the server is sending the output you posted. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#troubleshooting

Comment: @ErikCederstrand my admin just got back to me and she confirmed that I was getting the right email content. Also i did check the ,<Body> tag which was same as my email.body content. So to conclude, we were getting the correct content. Thanks again for all your assistance. !!!

Comment: @sDsV If I am understanding your comment correctly the <Body> tag includes the wrong information in the XML file, is that correct?  If so, were you ever able to resolve this and get EWS to return the actual body of the e-mail in this tag?

Comment: To future visitors of this thread, if this exact format shows up as the body in your call to EWS, then it may be the case that you are requesting from a "envelope journaling" mailbox.  Envelope journaling stores the original e-mail as an attachment to the e-mail with a body format that looks like the output @sDsV is getting above.  The attachment will contain the text body that you are likely after.